# I can't move a File in Python : File not Found Error

Tags: python, file, move, shutil, file-not-found

Related Code: This function is bound to the button "Move File"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TBLq.png)

```
def move_file():
  filename_url = "y2meta.com"
  format = ".mp3"
  space = filename_url + " "
  hyphen ="- "
  quality_file_320 = " (320kbps)"
  backslash = "\\"
  filename = '\\'+ space + hyphen +title+ quality_file_320 +format
  download_source = r'C:\Users\kevin\Downloads'
  source = download_source + filename
  destination_source = r'C:\Users\kevin\Music'
  destination = destination_source
  dest = shutil.move(source,destination)
```

title = the Text which I enter in the Textbox (i.e. Runar) -->!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TBLq.png)

When I try to move a File it tells me everytime "File not Found Error", but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code, because the file is in the destination.
A file that I want to move (i.e. Runar) !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtxUn.png)

I hope you can help me, and I'm sorry if this questions has been asked already, the solutions just didn't work for me. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `format` is a python built in function. Using it as variable might cause problems. Are your sure `source` final string is evaluated right?

Comment: @farshad yes, if I don't set it as r'C:\Users\kevin\Music', I get a Unicode Error.

Comment: I mean `source` in `shutil.move(source,destination)`. Can you use `print` to check the value?

Comment: @farshad The value of source is "C:\Users\kevin\Downloads\y2meta.com - Runar (320kbps).mp3".

Comment: Copy and paste the value into file explorer and see if it opens the file correctly.

Comment: Bruh. I have found the error, it's a missing space between "320" and "kbps". Well, the easy looking solutions are, most of the time, the hardest to find. But thank you for your tip with the file explorer. This was a worthy tip.